# If $ \dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2} = \dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)} $, then what type of triangle is $\triangle ABC $?

Tags: trigonometry

In $\triangle ABC$

$
\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2} = \dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}
$

then what type of triangle is  $\triangle ABC $  ?

---

My try :

By componendo and dividendo

$\dfrac{a^2}{b^2} = \tan A \cot B$

Not able to conclude, any help ?

Comment: It looks isosceles, at the very least. Set A=B and a=b satisfies your identity.

Comment: thank you, setting A=B gives $1 = \tan^2A $  Can we say isosceles right angled triangle ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there. Just apply the sine rule in the form $$\dfrac ab=\dfrac{\sin A}{\sin B}$$to get $\sin A\cos A=\sin B\cos B$; that is, $\sin 2A=\sin 2B$ and hence either $A=B$ or $C$ ($=\pi-A-B$) =$\pi/2$.

**Edit** Apologies to the OP for an incorrect first answer.

Comment: Wow! how did I miss that !! thank you so much xD

Comment: I am definately sure you reached to this point @John Bentin, what after that.$$\dfrac{a}{b} = \frac{\cos B}{\cos A}$$

Comment: @MonK: You are right. See my corrected answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer a little more, I am sorry.

Comment: @MonK: I have done so. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: It still doesn't, Look below$$a\cos A = b\cos B$$

$$a\cos A = b\cos (180-(A+C))$$

$$a\cos A = b(-\cos(A+C))$$


$$a\cos A=-b(\cos A\cos C-\sin A\sin C)$$



??

I am pretty sure I went in the wrong direction after it, Can you guide me please.

How did you reach to $sinAcosA=sinBcosB$

Comment: One more thing, We can be definately sure that $A+B+C=180^\circ$, but  $A+B=90^\circ$, It can't be established. Don't take this personal, I am trying to understand your answer :)

Comment: @MonK: In your first line, you need to replace $a$ and $b$ by $\sin A$ and $\sin B$ respectively, which you can do by the sine rule. From $\sin 2A=\sin 2B$ we get either $2A=2B$ or $2A +2B=\pi$ (because $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta$).

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2} = \dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}$$
$$\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{a^2+b^2} = \frac{\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B}{\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B}$$

$$\dfrac{a^2-b^2+a^2+b^2}{a^2-b^2-a^2-b^2} = \frac{\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B+\sin A\cos B+\cos A\sin B}{\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B-\sin A\cos B-\cos A\sin B}$$

$$\dfrac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{\sin A\cos B}{\cos A\sin B}$$
$$\dfrac{a^2}{b^2} = \frac{ak.\cos B}{\cos A.bk}$$

Because,

$$\text{sine rule}\implies\frac{\sin A}a=\frac{\sin B}b=k$$

$$\dfrac{a}{b} = \frac{\cos B}{\cos A}$$

$$a\cos A = b\cos B$$

$$\sin A\cos A=\sin B\cos B$$

$$\sin 2A=\sin 2B$$

Or, A=B.

So, the triangle is an isoceles.

Comment: you forget $2A=\pi -2B$ is also  a solution.